# Deny access if url is different from what was set in iframe tag

Tags: php, javascript, url, iframe

is there any way to deny access to a page if the url is different from what was set in the iframe tag?

Eg.:

i created a page named `index.php` in the directory `abc`;

i coded this url `http://www.mysite.com/client/client.php` to be opened in an iframe tag in the page index.php:

`<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/client/client.php">
</iframe>`

The user will see that page normally hitting the address `http://www.mysite.com/abc`, but if it changes its view to another link(throughout the menu available in its content) eg.: to the contact page. It should get out from the iframe and the address bar should be `http://www.mysite.com/contactpage` not `http://www.mysite.com/abc` anymore.

I've tried using the `IF ELSE` statement, but the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives the url from the address bar which in this case doesn't change because of the iframe. How can i check the current url access inside the iframe?

Comment: Could you clarify more by adding code or examples or print screens ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `target="_top"` for each link in client.php.

---

If you can't do it manualy, you could solve it with JavaScript (PHP is no help here). In index.php put the following code (uses jQuery):

```
<iframe id="client_frame" src="http://www.mysite.com/client/client.php"> </iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#client_frame").on('load', function() {
    $(this.document).find('a').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).attr('target')) $(this).attr('target', '_top');
    });
  });
</script>
```

It loops through all `<a>` elements of the DOM document of the iframe and adds `target="_top"` if the element doesn't have a target attribute.

Note that this only works if the embedded iframe has the same domain as the parent document.